# Extended (~24 hours) layover/stopover in Hong Kong

Tags: air-travel, layovers, southeast-asia, hong-kong

I'm traveling from Thailand to LAX in May and would really like to find an extended layover in Hong Kong, just enough time to see the city and I heard people doing that, but haven't been able to find any great flights through conventional means.

Is there a way to search for flights with such a criteria?

Comment: Did you try booking a multi-city trip on your airlines website? There are often options for that.

Comment: A stop on an international itinerary exceeding 24 hours would be usually be considered a stopover, not a layover, which could affect the fares you are seeing. It is not clear, however, what exactly would make a flight a "great" one for you.

Comment: Also consider matrix.itasoftware.com

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to be shared for a stop-over, you must limit yourself to 23:59 minutes. Most travel sites let you search for flights and sort by total duration. This will help you find the longest stop-over at the end of the list.

What often happens with popular routes is that you will not be offered such a layover because there are enough shorter options. What I've done in that case is do the same search but sort by departure time first and then arrival time. Take a note of segment which arrives the earliest at your layover and then the look for the segment which departs the latest. Then call, the airline and ask for a route with those two segment. I've done this several times but not with Hong Kong particularly.

For a longer stay you want a stopover and that usually has to be done with the airline anyway. You can try multi-city routes directly online but I've never seen it return a reasonable price for the ones I tried.

Answer (score -1):

I believe these people that had *extended layovers (stopovers)* in Hong Kong probably built the flight using 2 one-way flights. I have often used this technique when traveling.

Traditionally, it is done by going to your favorite flight search engine then **searching for one-way flights** to the stopover city and then from stopover city to final destination. Often times the traveler will search multiple options for stopovers instead of only choosing one ahead of time in order to find the best value. As a stopover is a bonus to a already planned trip, the destination of the stopover can be any place the traveler has not seen before. *The primary benefits of this technique are that the traveler can see more of the world, and often times save money while doing it.*

I used this technique so often, and knew the tedious and time-consuming method was something that could be automated. So, my co-founder and I spent the last 1-1/2 years developing [QuestOrganizer.com - The First Stopover Flight Deal Engine](http://questorganizer.com/). QuestOrganizer does all the time consuming work for you by finding the optimal stopovers between any two destinations then easily organizing them to create a multiple one-way flight itenerary.

Comment: Right now, this a bit of too much self-advertising, as the claim how "traditionally" stop-overs are booked is overgeneralizing. Sites such as kayak offer multi-city flights for years and find "reasonable" fares with that approach. Perhaps you can improve your post a bit in this direction (e.g., by stating that "often, good airfares can be found in this way" rather stating that this is the "traditional" way.

Comment: This has enough of a good answer that I, personally, can overlook the spam-ish-ness of it. However, you'll likely get many down-votes. For the future, please [read this entry on how to promote your product here.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: Perhaps some editing is in order then ?